# Python Webdriver Manager: Linux Problem on Webdriver Manager for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-manager

Linux Problem on Webdriver Manager Python

Details:

System - Manjaro Linux
IDE: Visueal Studio Code

Currently, I used the Webdriver Manager tutorial in Python to make my work easier. But IE and Edge are giving me problems.

The Integration:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
```

Chromium,Chrome and Firefox to some extent, but there I found a workaround that works thanks to Stackoverflow.

When running Edge on Manjaro Linux I get the following error:

```
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/91.0.864.70/edgedriver_linux64.zip
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - There is no [linux64] edgedriver for browser  in cache
[WDM] - Trying to download new driver from https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/91.0.864.70/edgedriver_linux64.zip
```

So the question is, is there currently no webdriver for Linux that allows to test IE/Edge on Linux as well?

Is there a workaround?

Comment: So that's the question, is it that clear? Because there are also webdrivers for Linux and IE/Edge.

Comment: It is a not well implemented feature in webdriver_manager for finding Edge version on linux. It's a known issue, should be fixed soon. You can track this issue here https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/243

Comment: Fix has come in 3.5.1 right now! Try >=3.5.1 version of webdriver-manager.

Answer (score 2):

Version you try to download - missing on the server.
Try change url for download. You can check all verions [here](https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/).

For example you can install valid driver ( other version ) from this url:

```
https://msedgewebdriverstorage.blob.core.windows.net/edgewebdriver/92.0.878.0/edgedriver_linux64.zip
```

Or change code to (specify neeeded and valid version to installation):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
    
driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager(version="92.0.878.0").install())
```

Comment: Thatś really helpful ! Thank you!

Comment: Get the same error with this sources and try to add some other Edge Webdriver. i tested different Edge driver. 

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager(latest_release_url="https://msedgewebdriverstorage.blob.core.windows.net/edgewebdriver/92.0.878.0/").install()) 

Based on that. But nothig works :(

Comment: My wrong, i upd. to valid code. You only need specify valid version.

Comment: Thanks Feuerwehrmann! Now it works but with some other issue :) 

Now MS wants the right permission to download. 

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'msedgedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687 any idea?

Comment: File don't have `executable` permissions. You can fix it manualy with
`chmod +x /here_is/your/driver/path`. 
But, in generaly problem in library ( after unpacking in python, file doesn't receive needed flags for execution )

Comment: `executable` permissions are fixed in webdriver-manager==3.5.1. Release was today.

Answer (score 1):

Try `webdriver-manager>=3.5.1`.

[Selecting](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/243) EdgeDriver on Linux and `executable` permissions were fixed in 3.5.1.

Released to pypi today https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/3.5.1/